# How to write regex to enforce maximum of 255 characters, with no spaces?

Tags: regex

What regex would allows text or numbers, or text and number (with no spaces) and a maximum length of 255 characters?

Comment: Give some examples of cases. Few valid strings, few invalid strings.

Comment: valid: "123abc", "1234", "abcd" Invalid: "123 abc", "123 45", "abc def", "#123abc", "ab.cd34"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{,255}$
```

^ matches the beginning of the string
[a-zA-Z0-9] matches an alpha numeric character
{,255} means up to 255 of the previous part (alpha numeric character)
$ matches the end of the string

Comment: At least in some regex flavors you need `{0,255}`. Not all of them allow the omission of the lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

If your regex flavor knows Unicode, you can use

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}]{0,255}$
```

You can also use

```
^\w{0,255}$
```

although that will miss non-ASCII letters in some regex flavors, and it will also allow the underscore `_`. If you don't want that, try

```
^[^\W_]{0,255}$
```